# Manga where the male lead has to team up with a female, and for their power to be stronger she needs to be intimate, and they fight these creatures

Tags: story-identification, manga

The manga from what I remember is about a male lead who is the son or grandson of a male who leads this division of powerful females that power up into this armour to battle these giant creatures which occur every now and then. One thing I remember is for them to be more powerful, they need to be intimate with their partner but that doesn’t happen for a while.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? What sort of time period was the story set in? And do you recall the hair colour of any of the main characters?

Comment: Does this take place in modern times? Do all the women live with the guy? Is the guy a late high school student/early college student (i.e. not a working adult)? Does the powerup come from non-sexual intimacy like going on dates? I've read a story similar to this, but the powerups start immediately, even in the first chapter.

Comment: Can you clarify if the male lead is partnered with a single woman, or if he's responsible for powering up several women? If he's the son/grandson of someone in a similar situation, is this father/grandfather still around in this story, or is that just a background detail?

Answer (score 1):

This is likely *[Val x Love](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/val-x-love)*. There are a number of differences from the question, but the basic structure is a match.

> High schooler Takuma Akutsu is terrified of human contact and just wants to live a quite life. Too bad he doesn't have a choice in the matter when nine Valkyrie sisters come barging into his home! They've tasked him with raising their level to fight off the monsters threatening humanity--and how will he do that, exactly...? By gettin' down & dirty to the max!!!

The demons would be the akuma - giant monsters that randomly show up. The designs are varied but in general they're huge and monstrous.

[image: Akuma]

As mentioned in the synopsis, the main character needs to "power up" the girls by being intimate with them, e.g. by holding hands while shopping together, studying together, or otherwise acting like lovers. This is complicated by the main character's anthropophobia and the fact that most of the girls dislike the main character.

[image: Holding hands to power up]

Powering up allows them to transform - not into armor, but they do get special uniforms.

[image: Transformed uniform]

The other major difference is that neither the main character's father nor grandfather shows up. However, Odin is referenced multiple times and referred to as the girls' father.